# How can i add multiple thirdpersoncontroller to hierarchy?

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

For now i went to the Assets > ThirdPersonCharacter > Prefabs and dragged two ThirdPersonController so i have in the Hierarchy now: ThirdPersonController and ThirdPersonController(1) but if i want to have 30 players(ThirdPersonController) and add to them to each one the same script is it possible to do it easier then drag one by one from the assets ? Maybe with a script ?

[image: Unity]

Comment: Of course you can do it with script, but that is so basic that I would just suggest doing some tutorials for unity. Look for instatiating GameObjects, seting parent to GameObjects and adding components to GameObjects.

Answer (score 0):

Some very basic things you can do is :

- Ctrl/Shift + left click multiple gameobjects in the hierarchy and then drag the script on it.
- Click on a single gameobject and drag the script on it, then hit apply at the top of the inspector, which changes the prefab itself and all references to it.
- Get one gameobject with your script ready to go and copy and paste that gameobject.